# How can I get the ASCII value of characters in a string in ARM Assembly?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

I have to convert the following code into assembly language:

```
void rotN1(char *str, int n)
{ // NB: str will be modified in-place
  char *p;
  for (p = str; *p != '\0'; p++)
  {
    int currChar = (int)*p;
    if (currChar >= 'a' && currChar <= 'z')
    {
      currChar = currChar + n;
      if (currChar > 'z')
      {
        currChar = currChar - 26;
      }
      *p = (char)currChar;
    }
  }
}
```

It's basically using a Caesar cipher on a given string (str), and n is the encryption key.

```
.data
        array:  .string         %[str]
        .equ    len.array,.-array
        .align

.text
        .global  main
main:

        nop

        ldr r2,=array           // pointer
        MOV r0, #0              // initialise loop index to 0
        MOV r1, #len.array      // number of elements 
    MOV r4, %[n]
        Loop:
                ldrb r3, [r2, r0]
            mov r6, # 
            B check_A 
            B check_Z
            ADD r3, r3, r4
            

        ADD r0, r0, #1           //increment loop index
        CMP r0, r1
        BLE Loop


_exit:
        mov r7, #1
        svc 0



check_A:
CMP r3, #97
BLT _exit

check_Z:
CMP r3, #122
BGT _exit
```

I haven't finished the code but while traversing the array I need to get the ASCII value of that character in each iteration. Is there a way to do that? I have to do this as inline ARM in C.

Comment: What do you mean with "get the ASCII value of that character"? Assuming your text consist of ASCII characters only (not any other encoding), the character value *is*  the ASCII value.

Answer (score 1):

> *"...I need to get the ASCII value of that character in each iteration."*

You already have them.

[ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) characters each have an integral value as shown in the linked table.  Integral values for characters ranging from `A`-to `Z` (as shown in the decimal column of the table) span from `65` to `90`, while  `a-z` spans from `97` to `122`.  So, in an array such as:

```
char msg[] = "Hello";
```

`msg[0]` has a value of `72`,
`msg[4]` has a value of `111`,
`msg[5]` has a value of `0`.

Note, the last conversion is because `msg` is initialized with a string literal, and [string literals](https://www.cs.uic.edu/%7Ejbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/CharacterStrings.html) in `C` are defined as a `char` array terminated with a `NULL` terminator.  Note that not all `char` arrays are required be `NULL` terminated, in which case that array would be a simple `char` array, not a `C` string.

Also, as you display in your post, an ASCII `char` surrounded by single quotes represents the integral value of that character.  eg in the expression

```
char aitch = 'H';
```

`aitch` now has the value 72. (again, shown in base 10)

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. - Thanks, I see that my example rotated to the wrong value by 1.  I removed that section.  It was not directly related to the issue anyway.

Comment: Integer values aren't inherently decimal.  I'd prefer to say `'H'`'s value in C is an *integer* constant.  (Or "integral" constant seems to be the standard C terminology.  Not much different from `72` or `0x48`.)

Comment: For example, `'H' >> 1` is `36` aka `0x24`, division by 2, nothing to do with base 10.  `'H'` has type `char`, which is often the same as `int8_t`.

Comment: @PeterCordes - Your penchant for syntactical and lexical precision is always enjoyable, and you make a good point.   _integral_ is a much better way to express this value. afterall using _decimal_ to describe a value that can just as easily be displayed as octal, or hexadecimal etc, is misleading.  Thanks for pointing it out... (I have changed the wording in my post.)

Comment: Cheers, thanks.  We often see in [assembly] questions beginners mixed up about "hex values" and thinking that decimal and hex need conversion when they're actually just talking about integer values in registers / memory, and how they're expressed in source code.  Not actual strings of ASCII digits.